# Recent flickr api problem

Tags: flickr

I just recently had problem accessing the getSizes API. I tested it in flickr api site and it returns empty string.

My security setting is set to public. Are there any changes or should I do that I missed. This just happened recently.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site is not blank, I just had to right click on it and view source. :) sorry for such a NOOB.